# Spring Boot deployed in PCF - Slow response time. How to optimice?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-boot-actuator, cloud-foundry

I started deploying Spring Boot applications in Pivotal Cloud Foundry, but I am experiencing really slow response times. Just for the "actuator health" end-point I am receiving an around 130 ms response time, which is extremely slow. I am not using the trial version.

Is there any way to optimice Spring applications by the manifest file? Or it is something about Cloud Foundry configuration that I am missing?

Thank you in advance.

Cheers.

Comment: There is no magic go faster button. If there were, it would be on by default cause no one wants a slow app :) Where is the latency coming from? An easy way to start breaking it down is to look at the `[RTR/X]` logs from your application. There are two fields `response_time:0.008489` and  `gorouter_time:0.000127` which give you some basic timing info. Response time is how long it took Gorouter + your app to deliver the request, Gorouter time is the chuck of the response time that was just due to Gorouter, not your app. Thus Response time minus gorouter time is your app's time.

Comment: Other notes, what's your memory limit? What's the app doing? Is it CPU intensive? Is it microservices and making request to other services or APIs? etc...  If your PCF environment has App Metrics deployed, you can use that to get more information from your application, it's able to pull custom metrics from actuator which can give you more insight into what's happening to your app. Lastly, for issues like this, especially if you have a microservices architecture, Spring Cloud Sleuth and tracing can help break things down more too.

Comment: Thanks @DanielMikusa That's a lot of information to investigate. I will take a look to these logs to gather more information.
About your questions: It is a microservices system, but I am checking calling to my Gateway, so no additional routing is happening. There is not memory limit as far as I concern, or at least I did not add any information about this in the manifest, so not sure if it is taking some default values. One thing is for sure, once started after deploying, the CPU is really high (around 94.2%)

Comment: Hello @DanielMikusa, coming back to you:
- response_time:0.004281 
- gorouter_time:0.000101
- Average request latency: 145ms
Checking with Postman, I can identify that most of the time is going on "Transfer Start". I will take a loot to this

Comment: Seems like you're on the right track here. Doesn't seem like it's on the platform or your application. Something is causing the latency on the request before it even reaches the platform. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @DanielMikusa. Do you ahve any clou about what could be the issue? Maybe some CORS related stuf? Just in case you have experienced a similar issue. Cheers!

Comment: It can be a lot of things. You need to trace the hops between your client which is slow and the service and see what the latency is at each hop. That's basically what we did with the access logs above. There will be load balancers in front of PCF, check the access logs there for request latency. Check on your client to see where the the time is spend. If you're connecting through a proxy, check how much overhead that is adding, etc... At some point, you'll find the hop adding the latency.